# Display Graphs in Admin Pages

Tags: admin

I need to display some graphs in admin pages. I know that there are lots of third party jQuery plugins available.

But I want to know that, is there officially recommended  way to add graphs to Admin pages?

Comment: Hi have the same problem but found solution for that take a look on below link at the end of the page you will find your solution [Custom grap using HTML and CSS](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-custom-widgets-to-the-wordpress-admin-dashboard/?nhtz=b&utm_expid=3606929-91.15T0nlf8TFCqo1W_BlZjGg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F)

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I also searched for that thing, but haven't got any suitable option. I used a third party library for showing my graphs and charts. So firstly I'll suggest you to visit those two directories [`wp-includes/js/`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/js/#L0) and [`wp-admin/js/`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-admin/js/#L0) Those are the **JavaScript** libraries included with **WordPress** by default. If you find nothing to meet your need there then please look for any third party **JavaScript** library for charts and graphs. I think it's better to use `jQuery` or `Backbone JS` based libraries cause those are already included with **WordPress**. So you just need to enqueue the third party scripts after `jQuery` or `Backbone` and do necessary tasks to show the charts. There are many third party scripts out there to show the charts or graphs. Just choose one and use it to your system.